# Conditional string based on Parameter from URL

Tags: apex, string, conditional

I have passed some Parameters across the URL string and I am trying to display one of two strings dependant on the value.  I'm not getting any errors in my apex or on my VFP but it is **returning blank**.

Here is my APEX code

```
// get and set sub from url
public String submittedForm { get; set; }
public String theLRProdID { get; set; }
public String showLRstring { get; set; }
public String valueOne { get; set; }
public String valueTwo { get; set; }
public String showString { get; set; }
public String showSub { get; set; }

public String getIDSAstring() {
    theLRProdID = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('prodId');   
    String showID = theLRProdID;


    return showID;
}

// String for leadership ready header

public String showLRstring() { 
    submittedForm = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sub');
    String showSub = submittedForm;
    return showSub;

    String valueOne = 'Please check over the details below and click the green submit button to confirm your Training Plan.';
    String valueTwo = 'Thank you for submitting your details. Click on the blue print button to print your Training Plan for future reference.';

    //If the form is submitted show value 2.         
    if (showSub != 'submitted'){
        String showString = valueOne;
    } else{
        String showString = valueTwo;
    }

    return showString;


}
```

And here is my VFP code

```
        <apex:facet name="caption"><p id="introText">{!showLRstring}</p></apex:facet>
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Is that my answer works for you?

Comment: I had to make some additional changes to your code.  I will paste it below.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of improvements are needed.

First of all you have declared method and property with the same name `showLRstring`. Make it distinct.

you have declared class level variable and local variable with same name as `showString`. Make it distinct.

Due to the following code and return statement, rest of the method will not execute

```
public String showLRstring() { 
    submittedForm = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sub');
    String showSub = submittedForm;
    return showSub; //method is returned from here
```

Controller

```
// get and set sub from url
public String submittedForm { get; set; }
public String theLRProdID { get; set; }

public String valueOne { get; set; }
public String valueTwo { get; set; }
public String showString { get; set; }
public String showSub { get; set; }

public String getIDSAstring() {
    theLRProdID = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('prodId');   
    String showID = theLRProdID;
    return showID;
}

// String for leadership ready header

public String showLRstring() { 
    submittedForm = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sub');
    String showSub = submittedForm;

    String valueOne = 'Please check over the details below and click the green submit button to confirm your Training Plan.';
    String valueTwo = 'Thank you for submitting your details. Click on the blue print button to print your Training Plan for future reference.';

    //If the form is submitted show value 2.         
    if (showSub != 'submitted'){
        showString = valueOne;
    } else{
        showString = valueTwo;
    }
    return showString
}
```

Visualforce

```
<apex:facet name="caption"><p id="introText">{!showString}</p></apex:facet>
```

*Note: I haven't complied the code, tried to guide you.*

Answer (score 0):

Assign the `showString` value to `showLRstring` variable before return statement.

```
showLRstring = showString;
```

Thanks,
Syed

Comment: thank you Syed for your reply.  But still empty...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got working

```
// get and set sub from url
public String theLRProdID { get; set; }


//Get and Set String
public String LeadershipReadyHeader {get; set;}
public String buttonClass {get; set;}
public String subAnswer {get; set;}



public String getIDSAstring() {
    theLRProdID = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('prodId');   
    String showID = theLRProdID;
    return showID;
}

// String for leadership ready header
```

Then inside the constructor

```
 private void getLeadershipReadyHeader() {
     //subAnswer = '0';

    //submittedForm = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sub');
    subAnswer =  myLeadershipReady.Automated_TP_Status__c;



         if(subAnswer != '1'){
          LeadershipReadyHeader = 'Please check over the details below and click the <span class="greenText">green submit button</span> to confirm your Training Plan.';
             buttonClass = 'action-button';
         }
     else{
         LeadershipReadyHeader = 'Thank you for submitting your details. Click on the <span class="blueText">blue print button</span> to print your Training Plan for future reference.';
            buttonClass = 'disabledButt';
        }
   }
```